# OpenGL doesn't work on emulators of games

Tags: debian, opengl, emulators

On both PCSXR and Mednafen I can't use the OpenGL to play my PS1 games. I have to use SDL, and the graphic sucks.

I have googled this a lot. Follow all that steps to delete the emulator files, modify some parameters and this kind of think. I have libgl1-mesa-dev instaled.

I'm using Debian 9.

Here are the log of Mednafen:

> Starting Mednaffe 0.8.4
>   Mednafen 09x configuration file found.
>
> Version detected: Mednafen 0.9.41
>
> Executing mednafen with command line:
>   "/usr/games/mednafen -psx.dbg_level 0 -video.driver opengl -video.fs 0   > -cheats 1 /home/john/Downloads/ROMs/resident evil 3.cue "
>   ERROR: Couldn't find matching GLX visual
>   End of execution caught.

My video card is some Intel HD.

> $ glxinfo | grep -E "vendor|version"
>   Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

My `dmesg` output is [available here](https://pastebin.com/Y4MkdadF), and my X.org logs [here](https://pastebin.com/279L8WiD).

Comment: That can be due to any number of issues. What emulator are you using? Have you tried changing it's graphics settings?

Comment: @StephenKitt Done.

Comment: @StephenKitt You're right about the Mednafen part (I'm embarrassed as I just woke up ten minutes ago) but I was only wondering if he had tried another setting.

Comment: @PeterGriffin I've never gotten either of those emulators to work whether I was using Fedora, CentOS, Ubuntu, or Debian. I've had much better luck with ePSXe. If you insist on Mednafen or PCSX then I don't have time right now but I'll look into it on my test box later on if you don't have any answer that works by then.

Comment: @StephenKitt No, I haven't.

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t know enough about Bay Trail (which is the chipset you have) to be of much use here :-(.

Comment: @StephenKitt No problem fella. I appreciate your attention anyway.